# Generate plot with embedded tools useable externally

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, matplotlib

I use a both latex and M$ Word for my technical reports, depending on the person I have to deliver it.

To generate my plot, I love using the tikz2pdf script given by [Hans Meine](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/tikz/process/) but as far as it produce pdf, there is no interactive viewer, such as matplotlib viewer, to zoom in, move curve and so on to analyze my results before making a picture. The point is not to make up the graph, but be able to go deep in the analysis by zooming or moving with the mouse.

So I start using matplotlib to generate plot, in order to have the same tool to watch and analyze results and to produce pictures. The problem is that I didn't find a way to execute matplotlib from latex, such as gnuplot.

In an other hand, I don't like the gnuplot viewer to analyze my results, it is not very user-friendly.

So, my questions are :

- Is there a way to use tikz and have **interactive** viewer (wich interact with mouse action) ?
- Is there a way to manage matplotlib from latex ?
- Is there another viewer, more user-friendly to watch and analyze results ?
- Maybe other ideas ?

Comment: Use QTikZ or (KTikZ on Linux) for it by modifying the preamble accordingly to include, say, amsmath, pgfplots options etc.

Comment: @percusse Thanks but this is not the point. I edit my question to be more explicit.

Comment: But now this is off-topic regarding the absence of TeX part don't you agree?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but couldn't you just use a regular LaTeX IDE, write your TikZ code using the `standalone` class, compile, and inspect the PDF in the internal viewer (which allows you to zoom and pan using the mouse)?

Comment: @percusse This is related to TeX as far as I need a tool TeX-compatible

Comment: @Jake As soon as you compile, you can't zoom in very deep, and moving is not easy as in matplotlib viewer

Comment: @Sigmun That doesn't follow from your argument. In this context, MATLAB, Mathematica etc. are also seemingly on topic, TeX related software as they can export TeX code or PDF/EPS graphics but your question is on the interaction not the TeX parts. The only possibility seems to be Asymptote but I don't really understand your question since, in the end, you'll end up with a PDF file and if PDF viewers can't help you then those details are not worth checking because they'll be lost in the end-product.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question:

1. Use [Tikzedt](http://code.google.com/p/tikzedt/downloads/list) or
2. [Qtikz/ktikz](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) depending on windows/linux or
3. [Tikzit](http://tikzit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your point of view. I answer by editing my question. The point is to be able to use mouse actions to zoom in/out, move plot... I am not looking for something which help me to make nice plot, what tikz2pdf to very well.

Answer (score 2):

For your second question:  You can use matplotlib from within LaTeX using the [PythonTeX](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package.  Since PythonTeX requires a cycle of running LaTeX, running a Python script, and then running LaTeX again, it will be a little slower than using Python directly if you need to do a lot of interactive work with your plot.  But you could always develop the plot code in pure Python, and then copy it into a TeX document once you're happy with it and are ready to create the final plot for the report.

Comment: I will try it, it seems to be what I am looking for... or not so far !